# pdo print info using given value pdo

Tags: pdo

```
function getCars($memebrNo) {
    // STUDENT TODO:
    // Change lines below with code to retrieve the cars of the member from the database
    $stmd=$dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM PeerPark.Car JOIN PeerPark.Member WHERE memberNo=:memberNo');
    $stmd->bindParam(':memberNo', $memberNO, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmd->execute;
    $result=$stmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    var_dump($result);
```

these are my codes, but i want to print like the following, besides can someone tell me am i using the memberNo given in function the right way? Thanks

```
$results = array(
    array('car'=> 'Gary'),
    array('car'=> 'Harry' )
);
```

Comment: You need an `ON` clause in the `JOIN` to tell it how to relate the two tables. Otherwise you'll get all cars, not just the cars belonging to the member.

Comment: Those look like the member names. What are you using the `Car` table for?

Answer (score 0):

To get a result like that, your query should be:

```
    $stmd=$dbh->prepare('SELECT name AS car FROM PeerPark.Car JOIN PeerPark.Member WHERE memberNo=:memberNo');
```

and then you should fetch the results with:

```
$result = $stmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` returns an index array containing all the values of the column. `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returns a 2-dimensional array where each element is an associative array mapping the column names to their values.

Comment: do i still need var_dump($result); then?

Comment: That's just a debugging statement, to see what the result is, isn't it?